# Microsoft Powerpoint 2013 - how to apply style to a piece of text?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I have a presentation, where I want to use some code snippets. I also would like to refer to functions within my text. For example: 
MyProgram.doStuff() does something.

For the first part (MyProgram.doStuff()) I would want to use a different style (some Courier New font with bold or similar). One possibility would be to just apply this font for every piece of snippet. But what happens, if I later on want to change all those snippets into blue color? Do I really have to manually change everything?

My idea would be I could create a style "code snippet" and apply it to a piece of text. Later on, I can modify the style. Is it possible? I might also try LibreOffice Impress, but even there I don't see an option to apply a style to a piece of text (I was able to apply it for the whole textbox, which does not work out).

Answer (score 1):

Word has styles and so does Excel to a lesser extent; PowerPoint doesn't, so there's no out-of-the-box way to do this.

I've got a commercial add-in that adds styles to PowerPoint and includes the ability to create "sticky" styles, so that when you change e.g. Comment style, you can have all of the shapes in the presentation update to the new style attributes.

Only hitch is that it only works on shapes as a whole; it can't deal with portions of text within a shape.  If you can live with that, give the free demo a try.  It'll create up to five styles.  If five's all you need, you're good to go.

http://www.pptools.com/shapestyles/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But yes, in my case, I would like to apply a style for a portion of text. Would be very time consuming to add a separate text box for every word I want to stylize.

Comment: Understood, and I figured that might be the case. So maybe customize PowerPoint's Pick Up Object Style and Apply Object Style tools to the QAT. You could at least then select some text that you'd already styled, Pick UP, and then apply it elsewhere. Modifying the applied style later would be a bit trickier but might be possible.